# Merging code from remote branch did not get all contents

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm trying to merge code from one remote branch - `release` to my local branch- `feature`.

In order to do that, I first checkout to `feature` branch locally and then hit following command -

`git pull upstream release`

I resolved conflicts but I can still see that some of files which were on remote `release` branch were not added to my local branch.

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result of `git status` after you pull?

Comment: This can't really happen under normal conditions.  Are you sure the remote branch actually has those files?

Comment: Do you have .gitignore in your local repo which ignore the files?

Comment: `git status` shows other modified or newly added files but still some files are missing when I compare with remote branch code and yes remote branch has that code and checked on github.

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, these are Java files and not added in .gitgnore

Comment: Post `git status` in your question in a code block. Sounds like you didn't finish the pull properly.

Comment: @TDHM How did you resolve the merge conflicts, did you use `git add .` before finishing pulling changes?

Comment: Based on what I want from`HEAD ... ==== ...<<<<<`, I resolved change and did did `git add .`. But `git add .` is later step, after pull changes should have come as they were on remote branch.

Comment: Seems the pull/merge was not completed. You should use `git commit` to finish the pull/merge. The flow to resolve conflicts when pull changes as: `git pull` -> modify conflict file(s) -> `git add .` -> `git commit`.

Comment: @TDHM Do you have the similar issue for `git pull` afterwards?